# why my jsonStore doesn't have any data?

Tags: extjs4, jsonstore

i had a jsonStore like this

```
var ch01_store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad:true,

        storeId: 'ch01_store',
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: 'index.php/test/get_ch01/10',
            method: 'POST'
        }),
        root: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'results',
        remoteSort: true,
        fields: [
            {name: 'date_time', mapping: 'date_time'},
            {name: 'chart_data', mapping: 'chart_data'}
        ]
    });
```

and the "localhost/myweb/index.php/test/get_ch01/10" url is resulting this on the page

```
   {
   "success": true,
   "results": 10,
   "data": [{
         "date_time": "5/12/2012 13:13:33",
         "chart_data": "3.5"
      },
      {
         "date_time": "5/12/2012 13:13:34",
         "chart_data": "0.0"
      },
      {
         "date_time": "5/12/2012 13:13:35",
         "chart_data": "3.5"
      },
      {
         "date_time": "5/12/2012 13:13:36",
         "chart_data": "0.0"
      },
      {
         "date_time": "5/12/2012 13:13:4",
         "chart_data": "0.0"
      },
      {
         "date_time": "5/12/2012 13:13:5",
         "chart_data": "3.5"
      },
      {
         "date_time": "5/12/2012 13:13:6",
         "chart_data": "0.0"
      },
      {
         "date_time": "5/12/2012 13:13:7",
         "chart_data": "3.5"
      },
      {
         "date_time": "5/12/2012 13:13:8",
         "chart_data": "0.0"
      },
      {
         "date_time": "5/12/2012 13:13:9",
         "chart_data": "3.5"
      }
   ]
}
```

but when i'm execute

```
console.log(ch01_store.getCount());
```

the log show zero
and I'm trying to populate it on a gridPanel, the result is still empty, can anyone help me?

Comment: 1. do you see in the console how data is requested and retrieved? 2. try adding `sucessProperty: 'success'` but that should be default value

Comment: @sha : I didn't see successProperty config on JsonStore documentation, i tried it any way and still not work

Comment: do you see in the network traffic how store data is retrieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Proxy like this and try:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'xxxxxx'
        }
}
```